# ODE Separating Variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When using separating variables to solve

$a(x)\beta (y)dx + \alpha (x)b(y)dy = 0$

First suppose $\alpha (x)\beta (y) \ne 0$ everywhere, then it is equivalent to solve

$\frac{{a(x)}}{{\alpha (x)}}dx + \frac{{b(y)}}{{\beta (y)}}dy = 0$

and we get general solutions.

Then check the roots of $\alpha (x)\beta (y) = 0$ and we get constant solutions.

I wonder whether these two steps are enough. There might be situations where $\alpha (x)\beta (y) = 0$ everywhere or at a single point only. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Your equation just amounts to $f(x)dx+g(y)dy=0$ which in turn is equivalent to the ordinary differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-f(x))}{g(y))}=F(x,y)$, which is variables separable. More precisely, the diff eq has a unique solution in a nbhd of   $x_{0}$ for $y(x_{0})=y_{0}$ whenever $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ exists and is continous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$

Comment: For example, in $xdy + ydx = 0$ if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ at a single point, we cannot use separating variables. How can we deal with this?

Comment: At points where $F_{y}$ is not continuous you really can't say anything. There may be no solution, one, or infinitely many. Zill's book on Diff Eq covers this pretty thoroughly.